# React to bluetooth button being pressed in my application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, bluetooth

I want my application to be notified when the user hits/selects the bluetooth button but it keeps going to the voice control. I have tried beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents but I was not able to get it to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: More info needed: Which bluetooth button? which voice control? what are you trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: My bluetooth headset has one button and I would like my application to react to it being selected when it is opened. A good comparison would be if if my app was open and the user hit the button on their headset I would like the button to react as selected.

Comment: Do you know if the headset actually advertises said button as a subscribable service or characteristic? If so do you know what the CBUUID for it is? Have you worked much with CoreBluetooth before? Or is this the first time you're trying to use it? :)